# C# & ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : interaction with Nginx and SSL

Tags: c#, linux, rest, nginx, curl

I have C# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, hosted on Linode (Ubuntu server) that is running Nginx.

Goal of my application is to mediate request between desktop application and third party API that is using oauth2. So my api handle access token issuing with third party API and then use it to call one resource on third party API. So there are two calls from my API to third party API, first is for access token and second is for desired resource. Second call needs client certificate and access token to be called.

Call for access token works fine, but second call fails with exception:

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> Inner: Unable to write data to the transport connection: Connection reset by peer

So I tried to debug this problem on my PC, but it works like a charm.

Then I thought that problem is on server, so I called second call with curl from terminal and it worked.

So it only fails when it is running on server with Nginx.

I am a beginner with Nginx, and documentation didn't help.

Is there any particular part of documentation I need to pay attention again?

Comment: LS is performed before an HTTP Request is sent to establish an encryption key to be used with HTTPS (secure). If TLS fails you never send the HTTP Request. OAUTH2 is authentication that is performed after the connection completes. Nginx is a proxy server (see : en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx). You have two certificates. First is the certificate that is used for getting the TLS key. Second certificate is for the authentication.

Comment: I believe the SSL error is misleading.  In c# you cannot detect the SSL/TLS error because it is done at a low level interface.   So the SSL error is really a timeout error indicating the connection did not complete.  You first call is completing.  You are sending a HTTP Request and getting back an HTTP Response.  Your second connection is failing and you are reaching a timeout when the connection fails to complete.  The second connection you may need to turn off the proxy.  The proxy is probably giving you the error.